# Debug app that runs at boot

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I am using Android Studio.

I added a BroadcastReceiver for my app that receives android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED, the receiver just shows up a Toast for testing. The problem is I get "App has stopped" message just after Android starts up.

My first question is: is there anyway to debug that at startup and see where is the problem by myself? Because I can't see any log referring to that problem in Android Studio.

My second question is related to the problem itself. Here is the code:
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".AutoStartReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Java: BroadcastReceiver

```
public class AutoStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

The third question is: Is it OK to do some heavy work (read some files and set the AlarmManager) in the receiver rather than creating a service? because as of API 26 Android is putting a lot of restriction to services.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps that launch on boot can be debugged the second your device gets a debugging connection, which usually happens just before the app itself would boot. Just open logcat and watch for the device and app to pop up after reboot. Note that this assumes the app is debuggable. Apps that aren't will simply not show any logs.

You get the `MyApp has unfortunately stopped` message for the obvious reason of this code:

```
public class AutoStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

You throw an exception, meaning it'll stop.

As for what you do in the service, as long as it uses within a reasonable amount of RAM and processor (extremely heavy services are more likely to be killed to save battery and memory) you're good to go

Comment: For most part, that was it. But I can't get the log of the app when it is loaded at Android Startup, the log is empty

Answer (score 5):

For the debugging part I used this (in the Terminal, when the emulator is on) :

```
adb shell am set-debug-app -w --persistent <your.app.package>
```

to start debugging, then click *Attach debugger to android process* when the app prompts for it on the emulator. [image]

To disable this:

```
adb shell am clear-debug-app <your.app.package>
```

Found answer here : https://medium.com/@elye.project/debug-app-deeplink-at-launch-time-bdb2cf04a9e6